# Python: In-place "not'ing" of booleans

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, assignment-operator

I sometimes have a dictionary of booleans like the following;

```
d = {'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': False}
```

which I use as a collection of switches which all have to be on (`True`) in order for some operation to happen. While iterating, these switches are then flipped, e.g.

```
for char in text:
    if char == '0':
        d['a'] = not d['a']  # State of 'a' is switched
    ...
```

The fact that `'a'` has to be looked up twice in the above bothers me. Were I to represent the values of the switches by `1` and `-1` I could do the switching like `d['a'] *= -1`, which only reference the `d['a']` once.

Ideally Python would supply me with an in-place "not assignment" operator.

Comment: It might make more sense to just add/remove from a Set (in the Set means `True`, `False` otherwise) instead of trying to toggle dictionary values. Depends on the specific use case.

Comment: @Carcigenicate How can I do this "adding or removing" in a single statement?

Comment: You can use almost the same syntax as what your answer is suggesting: `s = {1, 2}; s ^= {3}; print(s); s ^= {3}; print(s)`. My original suggestion was more concerning using a dictionary in this use case in general. A Set strikes me as a better container, unless you need to track all three of "seen, but true", "seen, but false", and "unseen", in which case a dictionary *would* make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my operator! One can use the bitwise XOR assignment operator,

```
d['a'] ^= True
```

I haven't gotten my head around how the bitwise operators should be used with general Python types, but I guess they work as expected with respect to booleans.